# C#, Classes inside Original Class bad programming practice?

Tags: c#

I have been following a workshop whilst I'm learning C#.

One of the class exercises that was given was to create a program that prints your name out into the console.

I have developed this.

My questions is .. is putting other classes into the main class a bad programming practice? I figure I'd ask before I started making habits! Should I just create a seperate class, incase I want to expand it to an actual project?

```
class Exercise1
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Character myCharacter = new Character();
        myCharacter.name = "tekaC";

        Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}!", myCharacter.name); //Prints the character's name into the Console output
    }
}
class Character
{
    public string name;
}
```

Comment: You're not placing another class inside your main class... you simply have another class declaration in the same file.

Comment: You haven't added a class inside your main class in the code sample? I'm guessing you might mean having multiple classes in the 1 file? It makes no difference, if that's the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear whether you mean:

- Nesting one class within another
- Keeping two top-level classes within the same source file

The latter is almost always a bad idea - class `Foo` should almost always be declared in `Foo.cs` so that it's easy to find. There *are* exceptions to this - for example, in Noda Time I have several delegates declared in a single file called [`Delegates.cs`](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/source/browse/src/NodaTime/Delegates.cs), but that's a special case - there's no code involved, and once you know that if you want to find any delegate, you look in `Delegates.cs`, it's fine.

Nested classes are fine when used appropriately - but I would *default* to creating new top-level classes. I rarely use nested classes *unless* they're meant to be implementation details which *only* the containing class is interested in. I usually make them private for exactly that reason - none of the rest of the code in the project needs to know about them at all.

One other point about your current code: you've got a public field, which is generally poor encapsulation. You should use a property instead, so that you can hide the implementation details. You probably want to give the `Character` class a constructor which takes the name at construction time too - you could then potentially make the underlying field `readonly`. For example:

```
// You may not want it to be internal, and you may not want it to be sealed -
// but you should think about both decisions.
internal sealed class Character
{
    private readonly string name;

    internal Character(string name)
    {
        if (name == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
        }
        this.name = name;
    }

    internal string Name { get { return name; } }
}
```

Comment: I fixed the indentation and it seems he's asking about placing multiple classes in the same file.

Comment: +1; I put multiple classes into the same file for years, until I finally figured out how painful it is to navigate other people's code...

Comment: Thanks a ton for the very indepth explanation! I guess I need to do some more studying! Much appreciated 8)
I assume by adding a constructor , you mean such things as "static" ?

Comment: @tekac: No, I mean a constructor... I'll add a sample in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't put a class in another class at all! You've just put 2 classes in the same file, which is really a personal preference. (I have some files with 5-6 interelated classes edit: omg Jon Skeet disagrees with me oh noez! :) ).

So in your example, you have 2 classes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the two classes are in one file?

One class per file is generally accepted as the way to do it, and in some languages is necessary.